# PostgreSQL ERROR: function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL to sort database. When I'm calling that query I have simple problem which I tried to solve for many ours, but it's still doesn't work.
I'm trying to split one table to many different.

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD COLUMN nationality TEXT,
ADD COLUMN place_of_birth TEXT,
ADD COLUMN date_of_birth INTEGER,
ADD COLUMN date_of_death INTEGER;

-- perform update
-- part which is not working

WITH splitted_data AS (
SELECT
  title,
  s [1] AS nationality,
  s [4] AS place_of_birth,
  s [5] AS date_of_birth,
  s [6] AS date_of_death,
  object_id
FROM
  table,
  regexp_matches(table.artist_bio, '\(([^),]+),?\s?(born )?(([^\.]+)\.? )?(\d{4})?(\d{4})?\)') s
)
UPDATE table
SET
  nationality = new_values.nationality,
  place_of_birth = new_values.place_of_birth,
  date_of_birth = new_values.date_of_birth :: INTEGER,
  date_of_death = new_values.date_of_death :: INTEGER
FROM (
       SELECT
         nationality,
         place_of_birth,
         date_of_birth,
         date_of_death,
         object_id
       FROM splitted_data
     ) AS new_values
WHERE table.object_id = new_values.object_id;

--until here

ALTER TABLE table
  DROP artist_bio;
```

Where:

title is other column contains titles

artist_bio is a VARCHAR contains information to be splitted

Here is a little part of the table: http://wklej.org/hash/3a2f6f17d20/

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Unrelated, but: you could write `from splitted_data as new_values` directly in the `UPDATE` statement. No need for the derived table in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is this subquery:

```
SELECT title,
       s[1] AS nationality,
       s[4] AS place_of_birth,
       s[5] AS date_of_birth,
       s[6] AS date_of_death,
       object_id
FROM table,
     regexp_matches(table.artist_bio, '\(([^),]+),?\s?(born )?(([^\.]+)\.? )?(\d{4})?(\d{4})?\)') s
```

I think you can do what you want by just using `regexp_matches()` to return a column in a subquery:

```
SELECT title,
       s[1] AS nationality,
       s[4] AS place_of_birth,
       s[5] AS date_of_birth,
       s[6] AS date_of_death,
       object_id
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             regexp_matches(table.artist_bio, '\(([^),]+),?\s?(born )?(([^\.]+)\.? )?(\d{4})?(\d{4})?\)') as s
      FROM table t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your advice. I'm trying to split the artist_bio for 4 different columns. When I used your code It shows me a different error about reference: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table.
Thank you again!

Comment: @axeMaltesse . . . You put your tablename where `table` is.

Comment: Yep. 
Figured it out while ago :)